# including c file includes by header file

Tags: c, include

I have those 3 files in my workspace:

**1.h**

```
#ifndef SOME_HEADER_FILE_H
#define SOME_HEADER_FILE_H
//code
#endif
```

**1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "1.h"
//code
```

**main.c**

```
#include "1.h"
int main(){
    printf("hello");
}
```

but in main.c printf is unidentified, is there a way to make it work while the relevant header is called in 1.c?
how can I link the 1.c and 1.h files?

edit: it's an academic assignment and I'm not allowed to make changes in the main and header.

Comment: Why don't you want to include `stdio.h` in main.c ?

Comment: it's an academic assignment and I'm not allowed to make changes in the main and header.

Comment: What are you allowed to modify then if neither the main or the headers? Compiler arguments?

Comment: Well just include main.c at the end of 1.c (and don't actually compile main.c) - but that's a really a _very_ silly thing to do in general.

Comment: If you are not allowed to modify either main.c or 1.h, then the only answer is to do as Mat suggested. However, this really indicates that either (1) you're misunderstood the assignment or (2) the assignor (instructor, TA, etc.) is an **idiot**.

Answer (score 1):

You have included `#include <stdio.h>` only in `1.c`, *not* in `1.h` or `main.c`. 
Obvious solution is to include it in `main.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way the `#include` macro works (it expands the whole header file that you include at the line where you call the macro), you actually don't need to include `stdio.h` within `main.c` as long as `stdio.h` is included in a header file that `main.c` includes.

Hopefully this makes it clear:

### main.c

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    printf("I can call this function thanks to test.h!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

### test.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

This will work just fine.

But this is *not* the same as being able to use a function that a `.c` file has access to based on its own `#include` definition just because you cross-compiled them. In that case the `other.c` file that calls `#include <stdio.h>` will get `printf()`, but `main.c` does not.

In this setup,

### main.c

```
int main()
{
    printf("I don't have any way to call this...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

### test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

You will not have any way for main to know what printf() is, even if you cross-compile the two. test.c knows what printf() is but not main.

What you want is to have `#include <stdio.h>` in `other.h`, and then `#include "other.h"` in `main.c`.

But for future reference, this is probably poor practise as it should be immediately apparent what each file's requirements are so that you get a good sense of what its job is.

So here's what I would probably suggest as the best solution:

### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    printf("I can call this all on my own.\n");
    return 0;
}
```